# if statements and click();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a function that takes 4 arguments. Then, it will put the value of the argument in a div. If the user clicks on a div, it will run a function. Then, it will delete the value that was put in the choice divs.

```
var fullDialogChoices = function(choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4) {
    $("#choice1").html("<p>" + choice1 + "</p>");
    $("#choice2").html("<p>" + choice2 + "</p>");
    $("#choice3").html("<p>" + choice3 + "</p>");
    $("#choice4").html("<p>" + choice4 + "</p>");
    choiceDisplayVar = true;
    if(choiceDisplayVar == true) {
        $("#choice1").click(function() {
            addDialogUser_0(choice1)
            deleteChoicesVar = true;
            choiceDisplayVar == false;
        });
        $("#choice2").click(function() {
            addDialogUser_0(choice2)
            deleteChoicesVar = true;
            choiceDisplayVar = false;
        });
        $("#choice3").click(function() {
            addDialogUser_0(choice3)
            deleteChoicesVar = true;
            choiceDisplayVar = false;
        });
        $("#choice4").click(function() {
            addDialogUser_0(choice4)
            deleteChoicesVar = true;
            choiceDisplayVar = false;
        });
    }
    else if(deleteChoicesVar == true) {
        closeChoices();
        deleteChoiceVar = false;
        choiceDisplayVar = false;

    }
}
```

I know I am not formatting the function correctly. Can someone show me how to make it so when the user click on one div, he cannot click on others and it will do what is in the else if statement. Right now, the user can keep clicking on the choice div and run the function it is associated with.

Thanks!

*Update*
Thanks guys, I am sorry it wasn't really clear but I found out what to do.

Comment: You've got to be clearer than that to enable us answer the question. Two points: 1) each call of the function sets `choiceDisplayVar=true` --- you do not need an `if - else` as the `else` will never be executed. 2) Each call of the function sets up click event listeners, in the end you end up with multiple listeners - same event, same handler ... not so good. What's your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the `if` inside the `click` handler, not when binding all the handlers. There's no need to bind the handlers inside the function, you can do that globally. They won't do anything until you call the function, since that sets `choiceDisplayVar` to `true`.

```
var choiceDisplayVar = false;
var fullDialogChoices = function(choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4) {
    $("#choice1").html("<p>" + choice1 + "</p>");
    $("#choice2").html("<p>" + choice2 + "</p>");
    $("#choice3").html("<p>" + choice3 + "</p>");
    $("#choice4").html("<p>" + choice4 + "</p>");
    choiceDisplayVar = true;
}
$("#choice1, #choice2, #choice3, #choice4").click(function() {
    if (choiceDisplayVar) {
        addDialogUser_0($(this).text());
        $(this).text(""); // Remove the value from the clicked choice DIV
        closeChoices();
        deleteChoicesVar = true;
        choiceDisplayVar = false;
    }
});
```

I'm not exactly sure how `deleteChoicesVar` fits into this, so I'm not sure if it should be `true` or `false`.

Comment: I believe you meant `#choice1,#choice2,#choice3,#choice4` not `#choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4`